How do I alter a database when a user disconnects from my web app? (Supabase)
I have a web app. This web app lists available live calls in the home page.
The web app should remove the live call from the home page when there is only 1 user in the live call and that user disconnects.
I tried altering my database when a user disconnects from Supabase Realtime Presence, but found no way to do that.
I was expecting a method to alter my database when a user disconnects from Supabase Realtime Presence.
